# How to Draw grid on image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, grid

I'm trying to use jquery to create a grid on a iamge on a web page i have. I have it working on edit fiddle but can't get it to work on my actually web server.

here's the edit fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/93cyX/34/

here's the webpage

http://dkraklan.me/wurmtest/maptest.html

and here's script and site source.

```
drawTable();

function drawTable() {
    var x = 128;
    var y = 128;
    var t = '<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="grxd">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); i++) {
        t += (i == 1 ? '<tr>' : '');
        t += '<td style="cursor:pointer;border: 1px solid black;"></td>';
        if (i == (x * y)) {
            t += '</tr>';
        } else {
            t += (i % 128=== 0 ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
        }

    }
    t += '</table>';
    $("#drawTable").html(t);
}
```

Comment: Call your function from document.ready().

Answer (score 0):

```
drawTable();

function drawTable() {
var x = 128;
var y = 128;
var t = '<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="grxd">';
for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); i++) 
{
t += (i == 1 ? '<tr>' : '');
t += '<td style="cursor:pointer;border: 1px solid black;"></td>';
if (i == (x * y)) 
{
    t += '</tr>';
} 
else 
{
    t += (i % 128=== 0 ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
}
}
t += '</table>';
SetTimeout(function(){$("#drawTable").html(t)},10000);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
table>td {
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
table.grxd {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<div id="drawTable" style="background:url('http://i.imgur.com/6kEWGL4.jpg');width:2048px; height:2048px"></div>

<script>
function drawTable() {
    var x = 128;
    var y = 128;
    var t = '<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="grxd">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); i++) {
        t += (i == 1 ? '<tr>' : '');
        t += '<td style="cursor:pointer;border: 1px solid black;"></td>';
        if (i == (x * y)) {
            t += '</tr>';
        } else {
            t += (i % 128=== 0 ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
        }

    }
    t += '</table>';
   return t;
}
document.getElementById("drawTable").innerHTML = drawTable();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

By using getElementById you will print the grid on map where drawTable id is created.When you write a function, function should return a value , so it return the value and called i in getElementById.

Comment: I didn't downvote your post but a code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)